# jQuery form code error used for automatic submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
var inpt = $('#input-box').val();
if (inpt != '') {
    $('form').submit();
    alert('Voila!');           // (1)
} else {
alert('fill something man');   // (2)
}
```

I am using this code to automatically submit the form as soon as the page loads.
Here I am unable to use the jquery `$(document).ready()` function because I m in GreaseMonkey environment.
The form is automatically filled, I used `(2)` statement for exceptional cases.

I get no alerts! neither from `(1)` nor from `(2)`.

UPDATE:

```
    <label for="answer">Answer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="answer" id="input-box" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @sombe Actually the page reloads with an error when the form has incorrect value above the form `<span class="error">Incorrect. Try again.</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the alert before the submit.

```
var inpt = $('#input-box').val();
if (inpt != '') {
    alert('Voila!');           // (1)
    $('form').submit();
} else {
    alert('fill something man');   // (2)
    return false; // to stop submitting
}
```

If you want it to auto-submit after a user enter a value then you can do thsi:

```
$('#input-box').live('blur',function(){

    var inpt = $('#input-box').val();
    if (inpt != '') {
        alert('Voila!');           // (1)
        $('form').submit();
    } else {
        alert('fill something man');   // (2)
        return false; // to stop submitting
    }

});
```

Comment: that's the same case. I guess I am getting problem in submitting the form, not alerting at first place.

Comment: I need to  know what's triggering the above function. If it's a submit button then you need to put return false; so that it stops from submitting

Comment: It triggers as soon as the page loads and the input box is checked for null value. If it contains some value then the form is submitted or else it will alert `fill something man`.

Comment: Do you need it to be behaved that way? Can you explain what you are expecting?

Comment: Actually I am trying to enter some value in the form one by one. If the value is incorrect the page would reload and another set of value will be entered into the input box Or in another case page would redirect and it would be success!

Comment: I have updated the code so that it's doing what you specified

Comment: Still not working. I'll update the que with form source (which is nothing).

Comment: @ysrb let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1618/discussion-between-tunetosuraj-and-ysrb)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert('Voila!');           // (1)
```

Will never alert, because by this time the page has reloaded due to submit request being sent.

Try:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    alert('Voila!');           // (1)
}).trigger('submit');
```

Comment: The form was not actually submitted instead the alert box came, I know this can't be the case as it only triggers when for is submitted but on submit the website either redirects to another page or shows an error. and this time I get none of them.

Comment: Hmm... since you can't use `$(document).ready()` have you placed the above code _after_ the form's HTML?

Comment: Well I am not sure how Grease-Monkey actually works..maybe its not after the form.

Answer (score 0):

Greasemonkey executes the code after onready, this should work. But is there a form on the page, and are you fetching the correct form? There's little information to go from here.

Try to check the function in firebug first, it should run there. greasemonkey needs some work to understand the jquery-thing. The easy way is to use var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; at the start, provided the page you're on has jQuery.

Comment: Yea,...there is only one form, so its pretty fine. By the way using FireBug along with GM causes strange behavior, read at the GM documentation http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:Other_Useful_Tools#Firebug

Comment: Lol, I've used firebug + greasemonkey for about 3 years now, it can be a memory hog but usually it works.

Comment: After using ` var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;` the whole script fails. So its better not to use that. and about firebug, I m switching it on :P